# oledb exception: the database engine could not lock table

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2007, oledb, oledbexception

I have a C# application that interacts with an Access database.
When I execute an `OleDbCommand` object to `ALTER` a table and `ADD` a new column, I receive an error:

> OleDbException: The database engine could not lock table  because it is already in use by another person or process.

While I can manipulate my data successfully. However when I execute the query directly in the MS Access, it works correctly.

Note: my database is closed and no person or process is using it.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

Use following connection string

`db.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\\<Your database name>;Persist Security Info=False;")`

along with following additional property

```
db.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Connection Control") = 1
```

In short, you need to open the database in exclusive mode to make an alter table query.
or you can also set this property in the following manner in c#

```
CN.Mode =adModeShareExclusive
```

I have not tested the code though but it should work for you.

Comment: What is the `db` and `CN`?  My connection string is : `"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=<My database path>;Persist Security Info=False;"`

Comment: The Jet connection is for earlier versions of Access and will not work with 2007 onward. The Ace connection is backwardly compatible.

Comment: You do not need exclusive mode to alter a table, you just need that the table is not in use when working in MS Access, and I am fairly sure the same is true in C#. I suspect that the table may be opened elsewhere in code.

Comment: Thank you `Remou`. Yes I had open the connection to select the Schema of a table before I alter it. I closed it after select and opened another connection again to alter the table and it WORKS.